# How to reduce timeout of HoldGesture?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

I'm using [HoldGesture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.core.contacttarget.contactholdgesture%28v=surface.10%29.aspx) in my application. However the timeout (approx. 2 seconds) is a little bit long.

Although [this answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/4a0f32bd-a493-48d2-b86a-29fa3f193ed9) says no, I'm searching for a possiblity to reduce this timeout. Is this possible?

Comment: you think the microsoft guy in the forum was lying to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the HoldGesture timeout is not configurable.